# How does Cpanel/whm execute linux commands

Tags: php, linux, bash, cpanel

I want code my own interface which can interact with linux shell commands.

i want to know (general idea) how does or in which language does cpanel/whm  use to interact with shell

e,g if i click on show disk usage then how does cpanel display the usage

Does it execute shell command and then parse the result or what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) in php and you're on your way to greatness! Be very careful for malicious users though (keep `rm -rf /` in mind for all inputs).